# Why is a non-blocking TCP connect() occasionally so slow on Linux?

Tags: linux, tcp, sockets, nonblocking

I was trying to measure the speed of a TCP server I'm writing, and I've noticed that there might be a fundamental problem of measuring the speed of the connect() calls: if I connect in a non-blocking way, connect() operations become very slow after a few seconds. Here is the example code in Python:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.4
import errno
import os
import select
import socket
import sys
import time

def NonBlockingConnect(sock, addr):
  #time.sleep(0.0001)  # Fixes the problem.
  while True:
    try:
      return sock.connect(addr)
    except socket.error, e:
      if e.args[0] not in (errno.EINPROGRESS, errno.EALREADY):
        raise
      os.write(2, '^')
      if not select.select((), (sock,), (), 0.5)[1]:
        os.write(2, 'P')

def InfiniteClient(addr):
  while True:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    sock.setblocking(0)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    # sock.connect(addr)
    NonBlockingConnect(sock, addr)
    sock.close()
    os.write(2, '.')

def InfiniteServer(server_socket):
  while True:
    sock, addr = server_socket.accept()
    sock.close()

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 45454))
server_socket.listen(128)

if os.fork():  # Parent.
  InfiniteServer(server_socket)
else:
  addr = server_socket.getsockname()
  server_socket.close()
  InfiniteClient(addr)
```

With `NonBlockingConnect`, most connect() operations are fast, but in every few seconds there happens to be one connect() operation which takes at least 2 seconds (as indicated by 5 consecutive `P` letters on the output). By using `sock.connect` instead of `NonBlockingConnect` all connect operations seem to be fast.

How is it possible to get rid of these slow connect()s?

I'm running Ubuntu Karmic desktop with the standard PAE kernel:

```
Linux narancs 2.6.31-20-generic-pae #57-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 8 10:23:59 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

It's strange that there are no delays with `strace -f ./conn.py`.

It's strange that there are no delays if I uncomment the very fast `time.sleep`.

It's strange that there are no delays on my Ubuntu Hardy system:

All these systems are affected (running Ubuntu Karmic, Ubuntu Hardy, Debian Etch):

```
Linux narancs 2.6.31-20-generic-pae #57-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 8 10:23:59 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
Linux t 2.6.24-grsec #1 SMP Thu Apr 24 14:15:58 CEST 2008 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Linux geekpad 2.6.24-24-generic #1 SMP Fri Sep 18 16:49:39 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux
```

It's strange that the following Debian Lenny system is not affected:

```
Linux t 2.6.31.5 #2 SMP Thu Nov 5 15:33:05 CET 2009 i686 GNU/Linux
```

FYI There are no delays if I use an AF_UNIX socket.

FYI I get the same behavior if I implement the client in C:

```
/* by pts@fazekas.hu at Sun Apr 25 20:47:24 CEST 2010 */
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int work(void) {
  fd_set rset;
  fd_set wset;
  fd_set eset;
  socklen_t sl; 
  struct timeval timeout;
  struct sockaddr_in sa;
  int sd, i, j;
  long l;
  sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sd < 0) {
    perror("socket");
    return 2;
  }
  l = fcntl(sd, F_GETFL, 0);
  if (l < 0) {
    perror("fcntl-getfl");
    close(sd);
    return 2;
  }
  if (0 != fcntl(sd, F_SETFL, l | O_NONBLOCK)) {
    perror("fcntl-setfl");
    close(sd);
    return 2;
  }
  memset(&sa, '\0', sizeof(sa));
  sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sa.sin_port = htons(45454);
  sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  while (0 != connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof sa)) {
    if (errno != EAGAIN && errno != EINPROGRESS && errno != EALREADY) {
      perror("connect");
      close(sd);
      return 2;
    }
    FD_ZERO(&rset);
    FD_ZERO(&wset);
    FD_ZERO(&eset);

    j = 0;
    do {
      timeout.tv_sec = 0;
      timeout.tv_usec = 100 * 1000;  /* 0.1 sec */
      FD_SET(sd, &wset);
      FD_SET(sd, &eset);
      i = select(sd + 1, &rset, &wset, &eset, &timeout);
      if (i < 0) {
        perror("select");
        close(sd);
        return 2;
      }  
      if (++j == 5) {
        (void)write(2, "P", 1);
        j = 0;
      }
    } while (i == 0);
    sl = sizeof i;
    if (0 != getsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &i, &sl)) {
      perror("getsockopt");
      close(sd);
      return 2;
    }
    if (i != 0) {
      if (i == ECONNRESET) {
        (void)write(2, "R", 1);
        close(sd);
        return -3;
      }
      fprintf(stderr, "connect-SO_ERROR: %s\n", strerror(i));
      close(sd);
      return 2;
    }
  }
  close(sd);
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
  int i;
  (void)argc;
  (void)argv;
  while ((i = work()) <= 0) (void)write(2, ".", 1);
  return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that sleep and strace cause the problem to go away, it looks like some scheduling issue where the server process is not getting scheduled to accept the connection. Although not scheduling the server in a 2 second period is an awfully long time.

Perhaps a tool such as latencytop may help reveal what is going on. You can probably only run that on Karmic (2.6.31), as the other kernels are too old I think.

Comment: The server process indeed gets scheduled. When I do a non-blocking accept() + a select() in the server process, the select() returns with a timeout. So 1. server does non-blocking accept(); 2. server does select(timeout=3) 3. client does non-blocking connect(); 4. server does select(timeout=3); 5. both select()s return with a timeout. So the server wants to accept(), the client wants to connect(), then why doesn't the connection happen in every 500th case?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's the `connect()` call the slow one?  in most libraries, DNS resolution is always blocking.  check if always using IP addresses makes any difference.

Comment: I'm running the code which I've included in the question. There is no DNS resolution there.

Comment: note that `sock.connect((host,port))` will gladly resolve `host` if it doesn't look like an IP number.

Comment: I know that `sock.connect((host, port))` will resolve `host`. But that's completely irrelevant in my case, in the example code in the question I use IP addresses, and it's still slow. Also I analyzed the program with `strace`, and it doesn't attempt any DNS resolution, or anything else which is obviously slow.